# cut command to retrieve 2nd part of words

Tags: bash, cut

i have a few name that I need to cut out and get the 2nd part of the name

```
agent-tom
agent-harry
agent-disk-see
```

I used `cut -d "-" -f2`
I only manage to get "tom", "harry" and "disk" 
question: how do I use the cut command in order to cut the 3rd agent so that i could get "disk-see" ??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're willing to consider tools other than `cut`:

```
pax> sed 's/^[^-]*-//' inputFile
tom
harry
disk-see
```

This command uses the stream editor `sed` to remove the part of the line from the start up to the first `-` character. I generally prefer `sed` for tasks like these since it's more adaptable when doing things other than simple one-level-deep field manipulations.

Having said that, this *is* a fairly simple task so a slight modification to your `cut` command will suffice. Simply use `-f2-` (field 2 onwards) in place of `-f2` (field two only):

```
pax> cut -d'-' -f2- inputFile
tom
harry
disk-see
```

Answer (score 4):

`cut -d '-' -f 2-`

Cuts from 2nd column to end and will get all regardless of dash count.

Comment: @Rachcha. If you say so. Looks like an answer to me.

Answer (score 2):

Adapted from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_%28Unix%29#Examples):

To output the second field through the end of the line of each line using the "-" character as the field delimiter:

```
cut -d "-" -f 2- file
```